# unable to verify babel for the file I'm trying to create.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, yarnpkg

I tried to install both React and babel.

```
C:\Users\Desktop\React Course Projects\Indecision App>babel src\app.js --out-file=public/scripts\app.js --presets=env,react
```

I'm getting the below error .

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Desktop\React Course Projects\Indecision App\public\scripts\app.js'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1299:33)
at output (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\file.js:90:10)
at walk (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\file.js:150:5)
at files (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\file.js:156:7)
at module.exports (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\file.js:184:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\babel\index.js:129:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

I have installed both Babel and yarn in My system

```
babel -V
6.24.1 (babel-core 6.26.0)

yarn -v
1.5.1
```

Is there something I should know about the mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 0):

Babel's `--out-file` option [will not create the target folder for you if it doesn't already exist](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4028).

There's two solutions to this:

- Create the `public/scripts` folder before running Babel
- Use `--out-dir=public/scripts` instead of `--out-file=public/scripts/app.js`, which *will* create the directory if it doesn't already exist.